# jquery animate after fonts are completely load

Tags: jquery, fonts, jquery-animate

This question might seem silly to some, but i have issue with the fonts that my client gave and animation of the same.

The fonts are of total 1.55mb that includes all the formats.

Now the issue is, I am using jquery animate and also complete: function so that all the elements animate one after the other in the page.

The text uses custom fonts sent by client.

**Code is like this:**

```
.... complete: function () {
            $s('#right-inner-content').animate({        right: "0px",
                top: "22px"
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                specialEasing: {
                    left: ''
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $s('#circle1').animate({
                        bottom: "170px",
                        left: "0"
                    }, {.....
```

Because of the fonts used, the animation is not behaving as needed, as soon as i change to web fonts like 'arial' or so...then animation behaves smoothly without taking load time...

Is there any option to solve this issue, as client wants to use their custom fonts with the same animation effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are on your server correct? Are you using the CSS @font-face to define the text properties of your elements? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp
(I know it's not the best resource, but it's easily defined here.)

If your style tag is before your script tag I believe there should be no problems. But perhaps because the font file is so large, you should give it time to load:

```
     window.setTimeout(customAnimation,100);
```

Google Chrome's Inspect Element -> Network should give you a good idea of how long the file takes to fully do this.

I also found this: http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/ it refers to a different problem, but should have the same outcome.

Mind .ttf only work with certain browsers. Eg. Earlier IE uses .eto. Also, because fonts are so volatile, if you need the font for only a few characters it might be best just to use images.